# SharePoint Designer Workflow Notifications

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, approval-process

I need to create a SPD Workflow where an email should be sent to a manager from a user and the manager has 7 days to review the email and approve it. If the manager approves the email before 7 days then the email should trigger immediately to CEO. Even if manager doesn't approve the email with in 7 days of time even then also sent to CEO after 7 days. How do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Use parallel steps in the workflow to wait for both conditions at the same time. At the end of both place an "end workflow" action to prevent the other from firing.

In the first of the two parallel steps use a "pause for duration" action with a duration of seven days. Then the email action. Then end the workflow.

In the second of the parallel steps use the "wait for a field change" action to wait for approval within seven days, then the email action, then end the workflow.